# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, opencv

I have been working on this error for a long time now. I have Python 3.6 and Python 2.7. I have tried to install opencv 2 and 3 in Python 2.7 and Python 3.6 respectively. I know the python interpreter I am using and I can interchange between them when I want.

When I run Python interpreter and write `import cv2` it does import it. When I run the code from command prompt it says *ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'*.
The module is installed. The cv2.pyd file is in `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages` I have attached a screen shot which shows the modules in Python27

[image]

I have used `pip install opencv-python`. I have downloaded the module from different sites and manually copy pasted it in the correct folder. Nothing works and I am seriously short of ideas now.

**EDIT:** I am on windows 10 with python 3.6 installed through anaconda and python 2.7 installed directly. Both have their variables set in the path

Comment: it doesn't work for python 2 or python 3, or both? have you tried passing the absolute path for `pip` (in scripts)

Comment: ```I have downloaded the module from different sites and manually copy pasted it in the correct folder.``` What?? Why?? That's not how it is supposed to be.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre works for python3 not for python 2. The code I am running only works for python 2.

Comment: @sascha I know!!! now you can understand how frustrated I am to do this

Comment: Simplest possible experiment: Using the same `python` that you can manually import `cv2` from, if you have a one-line `test.py` that reads `import cv2`, does `python test.py` produce the import error?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54147922/no-module-named-cv2-but-it-is-installed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Faced with the same issue on Windows 10 I downloaded the open cv binary from the [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).

Search the page for *opencv* and for and download the correct .whl for your system.  Then pip install it.  By example, on my system, after opening a **cmd** window I typed the following.

```
pip install opencv_python-3.4.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

I then opened python and the following worked

```
import cv2
print(cv2.__version__)
```

More info is available in this [Mark Jay video](https://youtu.be/PyjBd7IDYZs?list=PLX-LrBk6h3wSGvuTnxB2Kj358XfctL4BM&t=202).

:D

Comment: Not working. I downloaded the latest .whl from the above mentioned link and installed it. When I did import cv2 it was still not able to find it. So added this line in the code to point to the installed location. Then I was able to import cv2 successfully but then when I tried to use imread parameter I got the error "AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'imread'". Any idea where I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Does this answer help [SO:a/47859122](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47859122)?

Comment: OpenCV now builds official python packages. `opencv-python` is the canonical one. all of them contain the base modules, some contain contrib modules, some omit GUI functionality. install exactly one of them.

Answer (score 20):

In Windows 10 you can install it as

```
pip install opencv-python
```

this will allow you to import cv2 module

Answer (score 2):

[@SpeedCoder5's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49328226/2745495) applies only to Windows users. I am however on macOS (specifically macOS Monterey) and I managed to solve this issue by using the Jupyter Notebook extension in VS Code (Python 3.9) after I installed cv2 with

```
pip install opencv-python
```

[image: screenshot of jupyter notebook oj vscode]

Comment: this is the same advice given by an answer from 2.5 years earlier (the other answer). `pip install ...` is supposed to work on all platforms, maybe with a `pip3` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a **too old version of pip** which was 10.0.1.
I upgraded it with

`py -3.7 -m pip install --upgrade pip`
to pip 23.2.1 (for my Python 3.7).

Then I ran `py -3.7 -m pip install opencv-python` again and it worked.