# AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'imread'

Tags: python, opencv

(i'm on mac os 10.8.5)

I'm using Python 3 (through jupyter notebook) and trying to `import cv2`

I did `import cv2`  succefully, but when I type `im_g = cv2.imread("smallgray.png", 0)`  I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-5eb2880672d2> in <module>()
----> 1 im_g = cv2.imread("smallgray.png", 0)

AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'imread'
```

I also checked `dir(cv2)`  and I get:

```
['__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__'
```

I guess a lot of functions are missing...
Is it due to a wrong opencv installation ?
Actually I struggled a lot to get opencv and I guess I installed it 'too many times' and different ways via Terminal. (`brew`, `pip`)

Should I uninstall opencv and start over ? How can I do this properly ?

Thx in advance

Comment: Do you have another file named `cv2.py`?

Comment: I found a file named `cv2.so`. Actually I struggled a lot to get opencv and I guess I installed it 'too many times'.

Comment: i had the same problem, took 3 hours of troubleshooting, in the end, I found that I had named the python file that I was working in itself as cv2.py

Answer (score 11):

It might be the case that you installed it in the wrong way. In my case as well, I installed OpenCV wrongly so I uninstalled it completely then reinstalled it which caused it to work.

Please notice the sequence of uninstalling and installing:

Uninstall:

```
pip uninstall opencv-python
pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python
```

Install:

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
pip install opencv-python
```

Comment: concurrent installation of opencv packages can cause conflicts. never install more than one of the variants. they all contain the base modules.

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem, the reason was that my script was named 'cv2.py', let's try to rename to something else.

Answer (score 2):

Reader's problem could be, that a wrong library (cv2 package) has been installed.
I installed `opencv-python3` instead of `opencv-python` for example.

So in case you have PyCharm IDE, go to File->Settings->Project: *->Python Interpreter and see what you have listed there:

[image]

Make sure, you have installed opencv-python.
If you have also other similar names, it should be fine - in my case it works.

Comment: In case you uninstall some other package (like opencv-python3), likely this step will corrupt your dependencies and you may get that error again. In such a case just uninstall and install the opencv-python again..

Answer (score 1):

This might happen if you have named one of your files as 'cv2.py'. So when you 'import cv2', the system accesses your file instead of the actual library. So try renaming cv2.py' to any other name and your code should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, this turned out to solve the problem:

```
from cv2 import cv2
im_g=cv2.imread("smallgray.png", 0)
print(im_g)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check:

```
brew list | grep opencv
```

If it doesn't installed then try:

```
brew install opencv
```

Answer (score 0):

it works with me:

> pip install opencv-python
>
> pip install opencv-contrib-python

source : https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have just installed `opencv-contrib-python` and not `opencv-python`.

Try this out, it worked for me-

1. First uninstall:

```
pip uninstall opencv-python
pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python
```

2. then install:

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python==3.4.2.16
pip install opencv-python==3.4.2.16
```

You can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56667850/11667998).

Answer (score 0):

I faced Similar issue,On Ubuntu
I had installed open-cv using the comand:

```
sudo pip3 install opencv-python3
```

I Uninstalled opencv, By:

```
sudo pip3 uninstall opencv-python3
```

Then reinstalled it Using the following Code:

```
pip3 install opencv-python
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem.
And get a solution by changing the current ***`cv2.py`*** to ***`cv.py`***(You can name whatever you like except the name of packages in use).
**Little Explanations**

> Saving the current working file as the name of **cv2.py**, when we try to run the file it imports the current file with **`import cv2`** statement, not actual **`cv2`** module. This whole thing is causing this whole Error.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you have your file or folder named "cv2", it is not permitted in Python. The way to solve is change the name and then your code will be run

Answer (score 0):

The same issue has recently appeared within my code and had no idea of what's happening. Tried different methods such as uninstalling `opencv-python`.

Coming to the naming of the file that I am working with, I definitely had no problem that might cause a collapse with the name of the library.

I have deleted the `opencv-python`, cleaned all of the package-related caches, and then reinstalled the `opencv-python` and `opencv-contrib-python`. Now, it is working fine and I can say that no issues have appeared yet.

P.S I am using Arch Linux. If you wonder about how to clear caches, try looking at [this source](https://averagelinuxuser.com/clean-arch-linux/). I hope it helps. Keep learning and exploring, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I personally had to uninstall all previous installations dealing with opencv :

```
pip uninstall opencv-python
pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python
pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python-headless
```

Then I deleted all files that had to do with opencv too in site-package
after the uninstallation, files related to opencv like `opencv_contrib_python-4.6.0.66.dist-info` remained and caused errors.

Once all these files were deleted I reinstalled opencv:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

now it works for me

Comment: concurrently having installed different variants of the opencv-python package (base+contrib vs. base) can conflict. **bad idea**.

Answer (score 0):

using cv2 on vscode
i was having this problem but nothing worked. Turns out that i named my file as "cv2.py" so it was importing itself

*"Generally, the Python Circular Import problem occurs when you accidentally name your working file the same as the module name and those modules depend on each other. This way the python opens the same file which causes a circular loop and eventually throws an error."*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me once when I copied the file via save as. As soon as I deleted the second file, the problem resolved itself.

Answer (score 0):

go to site_package directory and remove all cv and opencv packages.
then run "pip install opencv-python".

Comment: Please elaborate on how your suggestion improves the consensus answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64658815/12846804

Answer (score -1):

Do `cv2.cv2.imread()`

This should work in most of the cases. Also, take a look [here](https://lucians.dev/install-opencv-on-windows10-and-python36).

Comment: I tried and this is what I get:

`---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-5eb2880672d2> in <module>()
----> 1 im_g = cv2.imread("smallgray.png", 0)

AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'imread'`

I also tried to rename `cv2.so` (in /site packages/cv2/) to `cv2.py` and got the same error.

Comment: @lotusam try do the installation again