# No module named 'cv2.cv2'

Tags: python, opencv

I am a beginner at computers. I use **Anaconda python 3.6** in **windows 10**. I have already installed OpenCV using this command:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

But when I try to import **cv2** using this:

```
import cv2
```

this error shows up:

[image: cv2 error]

How can I install openCV for python?

Comment: Did you try to install with Conda? Try conda install -c conda-forge opencv

Comment: @daniboy000 I tried that as well. The same error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this:

Create Virtual Environment

```
conda create --name opencv-env python=3.6
```

Activate the environment

```
activate opencv-env
```

Install OpenCV and other important packages

```
pip install numpy scipy matplotlib scikit-learn jupyter
pip install opencv-contrib-python
pip install dlib
```

Test your installation

```
import cv2
cv2.__version__
```

Comment: I tried this one and it says: `All requested packages already installed.`

Comment: This works for me too. but before 'pip install dlib' I had to run 'pip install cmake'

Answer (score 20):

Based on python opencv link: https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/

Step 1:
Uninstall the opencv first if you have previous/other manually installed (= not installed via pip) version of OpenCV installed (e.g. cv2 module in the root of Python's site-packages)):

> > pip uninstall opencv-python

Step 2:
Install the package afresh

> > pip install opencv-python

Hope that works!

Answer (score 3):

In my case, using Python 3.8 on Windows 10 and Pycharm (or VS Code as well), I have this same issue.

Finally I noticed that the Antivirus (Nod32) deletes the `cv2.cp38-win32.pyd` file that should be in the cv2 folder. I simply paused the protection, installed opencv with `pip install opencv-python` command and it worked just fine.

I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me because I setup a virtual environment with python 32-bit and my modules required the 64-bit version so it seemed there was a version conflict of CV. Changing the python version in my environment fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar issue. In my case, the issue occured because of previous dependencies.

```
!pip install easyocr
!pip install imutils
```

if you are running these commands first and then importing

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import imutils
import easyocr
```

then you will get this error. So you first import CV2 and then pip install easyocr or other libraries. This worked in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I used the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46854330/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-cv2?answertab=votes#tab-top) and it worked.

By running `pip install opencv_python-3.4.5-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl`

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem on Windows 10. Uninstalling via pip and then reinstalling in my virtual environment fixed everything up for me.

Here's a link that helped https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling `openCV` — it worked for me.

**To uninstall:**

```
pip uninstall opencv-python
```

**To reinstall:**

```
pip install opencv-python
```

Comment: Hi! Your answer appears to be quite similar to this one, which has already been there for a while: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56478888/13990016. Could you possibly edit your answer to add an explanation of how your answer improves on/differs from that answer? :)