# I can't create an recognizer using the lastest opencv version

Tags: python, opencv

I'm' trying to build a face recognition project with python. But I've found a problem, I can't instantiate the recognizer because  when I try execute this line:

`recognizer = cv2.face.LBHFaceRecognizer_create()`

I got this error:

> AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'face'

So I've searched for a solution in the web, much of them, suggested to execute this command on terminal:

> pip install opencv-contrib-python

it doesn't solve the problem, I've tried to reinstall to but the problem remains. I've seek information about the documentation but it looks that there's a miss of information about how to create an recognizer in the web.Do Someone know  how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me with a slight modification:

`recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()`

I added a P after LB.

I have a working example [here](https://colab.research.google.com/github/shortcipher3/stackoverflow/blob/master/61897746.ipynb)

Answer (score 0):

If someone knows how to solve the problem this post shows exactly the solution for this problems step by step, it's only follow the first answer:

[No module named 'cv2.cv2'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55360459/no-module-named-cv2-cv2)